# Axes.SelectItems() with DateTime based query?

Tags: xpath, sitecore, sitecore6

Is it possible to do a date based query using xpath syntax? Everything I have researched inidicates that this is not possible. I am querying a group of calendars and only want to bring back a month's worth of data - what strategies could I use to accomplish this?

*8/10/2010: Edit for more information*

I am building a notification system where users can get reminders for particular events. Reminders can come 4 weeks, 3 weeks, 2 weeks, 1 week in advance. I am storing this information in separate SQL database.

I need to do one of two things to keep my code as efficient as possible:

1. Do a select from my notifications table, then only bring back events with notifications associated with them.
2. Only bring back 4 weeks of events and then see which have notifications attached to them.

Comment: For a complete answer you need to post same reduced input sample.

Comment: I've added more information. Hopefully it is enough to give you an idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I've asked you for same input sample, because if dates are explicit present in your input then you can select by its string value with XPath 1.0 or by its typed value in XPath 2.0 . Also, it has been a proposal to add some sort of date stamp in XML data model (when node was added to the tree).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more, I'd say you should be looking at your information architecture. With calendars, news and similar type content, it is most often a good approach to arrange the items in some sort of archive.

```
Company News
- 2010
  - 01
  - 02
  ...
  - 12
```

And so on.

There's even a Shared Source project designed to help you maintain more or less excactly a structure such as this. Take a look at the [News Mover](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/News_mover.aspx) module.

Comment: Your approach is a step in the right direction. When I do my "select" I could pull the current month and the next month instead of worrying about the xpath stuff.